# Xcode Instruments output interpretation for iPad app

Tags: xcode4, instruments

In the Instruments under Allocations, for the "All Allocations" line the "Live Bytes" and "Overall Bytes" show a very small amount of memory (~2.5MB) and they seem to be very stable.  But the "# Living" and "# Overall" keep going up gradually.

Question:  Which columns are more important in term of finding out memory footprint for my app?  What are differences between "Live Bytes" vs "# Living" and "Overall Bytes" vs "# Overall"?

BTW: Instruments shows no leaks memory at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Live Bytes column for the All Allocations category is the best estimate of your app's memory footprint.

The Live Bytes column tells you the amount of currently allocated memory for a given category. The # Living column tells you the number of net memory allocations for a given category. The Overall Bytes column tells you the total amount of allocated memory. The # Overall column tells you the total number of memory allocations.

If you use the Leaks template, the Allocations instrument is configured to track only active memory allocations. When you track only active memory allocations, the Live Bytes and Overall Bytes columns are going to be the same, and the # Living and # Overall columns are going to be the same. Clicking the Info button next to the Allocations instrument lets you configure what the Allocations instrument records.

[image]