# Why are memory consumptions viewed from Activity Monitor and Instruments so different.

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, instruments

My app is a music player, it plays MP3's continuously from internet with AV Foundation. It has memory consumption issues.

When I look for the reason with Allocations or Leaks instruments, the Activity Monitor reports  memory consumptions of 50MB or so.
When I run the app with Product->Run, the Activity Monitor reports memory consumptions of 20MB initially, and it increases 100kB per second. Why are they so different?

Further more, the Allocations or Leaks instruments all have the 'Allocations' row. The right side bars in Allocations gradually turn into red. The right side bars in Leaks are always blue. The 'Allocations' row works differently in these two instruments? I use Xcode 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the last paragraph, the Allocations instrument is configured differently for the Allocations and Leaks templates. In the Allocations template, the instrument tracks all memory allocations. In the Leaks template the instrument tracks only active allocations. The histogram (the colored bar on the right side) reflects the ratio of active to total allocations, with blue indicating a high ratio and red indicating a low ratio. Because the Leaks instrument tracks only active allocations, the active allocations equal the total allocations, giving you a blue histogram. Click the Info button next to the Allocations instrument to configure what it records.

If you want to see how much memory your application is using, look at the Live Bytes column for the All Allocations category in the Allocations instrument. Also, take a look at the following question:

[Xcode Instruments output interpretation for iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507918/xcode-instruments-output-interpretation-for-ipad-app/6527376#6527376)